# R: How to search for a row by a condition, and then change that row?

Tags: r

Say we have a data.frame as follows,

`name<-c("alison","bob","carol","dave")`
`age<-c(30,31,32,33)`
`hairlength<-c(1500,300,1400,500)`
`data<-data.frame(name,age,hairlength)`

Let's say I have many, many rows of data and I want to search for the row that contains "bob" and change the hair length in this row from 300 to 350. So that if I view the data.frame, the hair length has been changed. How do I go about that simple process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is as follows. We match every row within `data` that has character string `bob` in column `name` and assign the value 350 to the column `hairlength` of that specific row.

```
data[data$name %in% 'bob', ]$hairlength <- 350
```

**Output**

```
> data
    name age hairlength
1 alison  30       1500
2    bob  31        350
3  carol  32       1400
4   dave  33        500
```